# "this" pointer (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, this-pointer

There is class definition like this:

```
template <class Impl>
FullO3CPU<Impl>::FullO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams *params)
class DerivO3CPU : public FullO3CPU<O3CPUImpl>
{
   public:
     DerivO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams *p)
       : FullO3CPU<O3CPUImpl>(p)
     { }
};

DerivO3CPU * 
DerivO3CPUParams::create()
{
  ...
  return new DerivO3CPU(this);
}
```

What I changed was adding another argument to FullO3CPU

```
template <class Impl>
FullO3CPU<Impl>::FullO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams *params, My_param *mp)

class DerivO3CPU : public FullO3CPU<O3CPUImpl>
{
   public:
     DerivO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams *p, My_param *mp)
       : FullO3CPU<O3CPUImpl>(p, mp)
     { }
};

DerivO3CPU *
DerivO3CPUParams::create() 
{
  ...
  return new DerivO3CPU(this);
}
```

However I don't know what to do with

```
return new DerivO3CPU(this);
```

because I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'DerivO3CPU::DerivO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams* const)'
note: candidates are:
note: DerivO3CPU::DerivO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams*, My_param*)
note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You've added a 2nd parameter to the constructor, and now you're asking what to do with it?

Comment: @mahmood, you are calling a one argument function... that you _just_ destroyed. If you want that code to compile, provide a one-argument constructor. If you try to call a constructor with 7 arguments and you don't create it before, it will give a compile error, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to add it to `create`, too, or use one stored somewhere.

```
DerivO3CPU *
DerivO3CPUParams::create(My_param *p) 
{
  ...
  return new DerivO3CPU(this, p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What function are you *trying* to call? No constructor of DerivO3CPU takes one argument. There was one but you added a second argument to it. So how could it possibly work? You must either keep the one argument constructor, or stop calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call the constructor of DerivO3CPU, and the only constructor available is

```
DerivO3CPU(DerivO3CPUParams *p, My_param *mp)
```

So what you should do is either provide the My_param* in your "new" call, or create another constructor that doesn't take a My_param* argument but provides some default to the FullO3CPU call.